# Are animals programmed to escape their pens?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm sure many of you Minecraft fans have noticed that animals always seem to try and escape their pens as soon as there is an escape route.

Are they programmed to do this? If so, is it simply to 'spread out' and find a larger area, or are they actively trying to escape captivity?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. There is a "Claustrophobic" aspect that derives from how the passive mob ai move in minecraft. 
Every game tick, passive mobs choose a block within a diameter of 16 blocks to move to.(when you hold wheat, your location is used instead.) If there is not block there, or there is no air above it, they abandon that path, and do not move. This happens most of the time.

If the block they chose is valid however, they will try to move there. If their pathing algorithm cannot find a way to get there, it will keep trying to find one every game tick until it finally gives up and chooses another block, how long it takes to give up depends on game version and type of mob.

What this means is that when a mob is in a pen, if they choose to move inside the pen they just move. If they choose to move outside the pen, (about half the time if they are near the wall, or more if the pen is small) they wait for you to make an opening, then walk towards it. Depending on the proportion of inside to outside this can be more then half the animals at one time.

I have exploited this behavior to create an automated slaughterhouse with pistons, tripwires and fire that turns cows into meals automatically.

If you just want a way to stop them from escaping, you can use trapdoors as doors to your pen, as regardless of whether the trapdoors are up or down mobs see them as a solid block.

Comment: Do you have any sources where you gathered this information?

Comment: Some amateur code browsing and much in-game testing.

Comment: Do you think there is a way to reprogram the code the create a "domestic" mob?

Answer (score 0):

No, any passive mob will not attempt to 'escape' if there is an exit made when they are contained. However, They will rush towards the player if the player is holding wheat, and if the player happens to be standing by the exit, it may seem as if they rush out of the exit.

Another possibility is that there is grass outside of the pen, but not inside. This would cause the animals to move towards the blocks with grass. The same thing goes for light, as animals in a darkened environment will move towards an environment that is better illuminated.

These are pretty much the only things, as animals will move more or less randomly apart from these circumstances.

Comment: Do you have a source for these claims?

Comment: The minecraft wiki. http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/AI#Passive